# Paypal IPN simulator - request is verified, but I get "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

Looking at logs I see that I received a correct response in my IPNlistener, but the pay-pal simulator page has a different opinion on it.

```
public ActionResult PpIpnListener()
{
      Loggr.Events.Create().Text("Listener begin").Post();
      var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

      string response = GetPayPalResponse(formVals, true);

      if (response == "VERIFIED")
      {
       // I get into here, and do nothing. Is there something to do except internall processing? Do I need to notify paypal somehow?
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable formVals, but you actually don't get these values from the form, but setting them by yourself with: `var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

You must create dictionary with form values based on your Request, and add a command after that.